# Creating XML for Jasper Reports

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I use the following Java code to create an .xml file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            ArrayList<MyBean> ll = new ArrayList<>();
            ll.add(new MyBean(1));
            ll.add(new MyBean(2));

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\mybean.xml");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            XMLEncoder xmlEncoder = new XMLEncoder(bos);
            xmlEncoder.writeObject(ll);
            xmlEncoder.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        ;

    }
  public static class MyBean implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private double fxEffectRealized;
        private double changeWPRealized;

        public MyBean() {

        }
        public MyBean(int i) {
            fxEffectRealized = Math.random() * 100;
            changeWPRealized = Math.random() * 100;
        }

        public double getFxEffectRealized() {
            return fxEffectRealized;
        }

        public void setFxEffectRealized(double fxEffectRealized) {
            this.fxEffectRealized = fxEffectRealized;
        }

        public double getChangeWPRealized() {
            return changeWPRealized;
        }

        public void setChangeWPRealized(double changeWPRealized) {
            this.changeWPRealized = changeWPRealized;
        }


    }
```

It creates an .xml file which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_02" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <object class="com.ch.reports.ReportJasper$MyBean">
    <void property="changeWPRealized">
     <double>12.206382535941362</double>
    </void>
    <void property="fxEffectRealized">
     <double>4.772624038704009</double>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
  <void method="add">
   <object class="com.ch.reports.ReportJasper$MyBean">
    <void property="changeWPRealized">
     <double>29.554973174761056</double>
    </void>
    <void property="fxEffectRealized">
     <double>33.64290090087834</double>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>

 </object>
</java>
```

But in order for it to be readable by Jasper Reports I really need it to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport>
    <MyBean>
        <changeWPRealized>12.206382535941362</changeWPRealized>
        <fxEffectRealized>4.772624038704009</fxEffectRealized>
    </MyBean>
    <MyBean>
        <changeWPRealized>29.554973174761056</changeWPRealized>
        <fxEffectRealized>33.64290090087834</fxEffectRealized>
    </MyBean>
</jasperReport>
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You could use JAXB to marshal the object into XML. See this example http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-marshal-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @ChristofferPass's suggestion of JAXB (Thank you!)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ListBeans lb = new ListBeans();
            lb.add(new MyBean(1));
            lb.add(new MyBean(2));

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListBeans.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(lb, new File("c:\\temp\\mybean.xml"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        ;

    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "ROOT")
    public static class ListBeans {

        private List<MyBean> listBeans = null;

        public ListBeans() {

        }
        @XmlElement (name="BEAN")
        public void setListBeans(List<MyBean> listBeans) {
            this.listBeans = listBeans;
        }


        public void add(MyBean mb) {
            if (this.listBeans == null) {
                this.listBeans = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
            }
            this.listBeans.add(mb);
        }


        public static class MyBean {
            private double fxEffectRealized;
            private double changeWPRealized;

            public MyBean() {

            }
            public MyBean(int i) {
              fxEffectRealized = Math.random() * 100;
              changeWPRealized = Math.random() * 100;
            }

            public double getFxEffectRealized() {
              return fxEffectRealized;
            }

            public void setFxEffectRealized(double fxEffectRealized) {
               this.fxEffectRealized = fxEffectRealized;
            }

            public double getChangeWPRealized() {
              return changeWPRealized;
            }

            public void setChangeWPRealized(double changeWPRealized) {
              this.changeWPRealized = changeWPRealized;
            }
        }
     }
```